# What is the fastest way to farm reputation with Ramkahen on level 100?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

They do have a Tabard, but the instance in Uldum is kind of long / a lot to walk.
So which dungeons can I actually use to farm reputation efficiently with this faction and which one is the fastest to complete since Boss rep seems to be the way to go? I am already revered and just need about 10k until exalted, however, I would like to speed things up since there seem to be only 1 daily in the entire area.

Comment: There are two dailies, but one is unlocked near the end of the Harrison Jones quest line, requiring you to quest almost entirely through the zone. (Which also gets you a lot of rep...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, tabards allow you to gain reputation from "any" instance (by "any" I mean probably only the ones relevant to that expansion set). I believe you can also get a small rep amount from doing PVP as well, but don't quote me on that, I could be thinking of PVP exclusive factions like Frost Wolves (horde).

Regarding your question: There are two instances that strike me as short enough to make "quick work" of the rep farming. The two are **Lost city of Tol'vir**, and **Throne of the tides**. The trash amount is quick to deal with, and some of the bosses can be skipped completely, like the crocodile boss in Tol'Vir. None of them are actually complicated and require minimum of brainpower, even if done in heroic mode. I've tanked, healed and been DPS in both respectively, both normal and heroic mode. Crowd control is useful for both places, a friend is good to have with you to support with that, unless you can plow your way through the content without a sweat.

**Tol'Vir:** It counts as "outside" so you can mount larger areas of the instance, making travel swift. Trash comes in packs of 3-4, rarely more. Can easily be CC'd and dealt with that way. At least one boss can be skipped. Relatively linear path to all bosses, pretty much a 'U'shaped path. Three of the four bosses summon adds to some degree, at least in Heroic.

**Throne of the tides:** Pretty straight forward shape of the instance, like a cross. One boss can be skipped, has an additional boss on heroic. Trash CAN be a bit brutal if you don't watch it, but those packs are few (big, tentacle dudes). The rest is simple. Bosses are complicated in the way that pure tank'n'spank isn't a really viable tactic.

Comment: I don't think I need CC at level 100 :D. But thanks for the rundown.

Comment: At level 100 any class can faceroll through the 5-mans with the old-content damage bonus. My squishy mage can even do Cataclysm raids with little trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The tabard works in all Cataclysm level 85 dungeons. See [this Wowhead page](http://www.wowhead.com/faction=1173/ramkahen#comments:id=1882722) for a detailed analysis which dungeon gives the most reputation. Summary:

```
Dungeon                  REP
H:Zul'Gurub              2400
H:Lost City of Tol'vir   2000
H:Vortex Pinnacle        1900
H:The Stonecore          2500
H:Grim Batol             3350

N:Lost City of Tol'vir   1275
N:Grim Batol             2150
N:Halls of Origination   1800
```

Comment: Running the Stonecore and Vortex Pinnacle also give an opportunity at a mount. I'm fairly sure you can only do one heroic run of a dungeon per day though (unless you queue via dungeon finder (which isn't possible in this scenario)). So after that, I think Lost City of Tol'vir is the best normal dungeon to run. Whilst it rewards the smallest amount of reputation per run, it is the quickest to get back to the start and reset it after the final boss. Grim Batol is fairly dense in monsters, but getting back to the start from the final boss is a long run. Halls of Origination is very spaced out.

Comment: There's no point on running heroics for reputation, as it is the same amount, and the mounts drop in normal mode too.